# Wrong events titles, in Gnome-shell panel calendar

Tags: gnome-shell, calendar

On Gnome Panel, when you click on time (at the center of the panel by default) you see a calendar. When you click on days in this calendar it is supposed to show your calendar events. but it shows one of my last events' title for all of them!

In Gnome Calendar everything is fine, in Evloution everything is fine, and all of them are synced with my Google Calendar, but in gnome shell panel calendar the titles are wrong.

Funny weird thing: I tried this extension [Calendar Improved](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2386/calendar-improved/), it is fantastic and useful, (I will keep it), it doesn't fix the problem and the titles are wrong but when you click on some event, there is an edit option, when you click on edit, the correct event with the correct title is opened. So, the events in the calendar seems to be correct and only the title is somehow wrong.